# Laravel eloquent where error with <>

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have query for **where** in native php

> where type <> 'point'

and I try convert to eloquent `laravel`

```
 ->with('payments',function($query){
      $query->where('type','<>','point');
 })
```

but it is showing error as follows:

> mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Change `<>` to `!=`

Comment: @aldrin27 both are working in Eloquent

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You're using wrong syntax. Correct syntax for [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) is:

```
->with(['payments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', '<>', 'point');
}])
```

Answer (score 2):

to parse the dynamic parameters within query try this :

```
$string = 'points';
->with(['payments' => function ($query) use ($string) {
    $query->where('type', '<>', $string);
}])
```

this will work!!

Answer (score 1):

If that is all you need to do with the query then you can just chain it like this:

```
->with('payments')->where('type', '<>', 'point') //chain more after this
```

Correct answer should be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436703/4161992) if you are trying to filter payments where the `type` is not equal to `point`.

Comment: There is no need to return `$query` from `with()` closure, that's not how it works. And your code will filter model, but it's clear OP wants to filter `payments` relation.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct @Alexey Mezenin. Did not realize that was intended.