# Laravel Query using with() statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Having trouble trying to use the with statement on a query as shown here

```
thePage::select('field1','field2')
->with('pagePhotos')
```

This query works fine, but what if I want to only get pagePhotos where the photoLocation="Miami".  This photoLocation field is not on thePage Model, and only on the pagePhotos table.

Below is a stab in the dark that doesn't work but it shows the logic I'm trying to get at, I hope!

```
thePage::select('field1','field2')
->with(
    'pagePhotos'->where('photoLocation','=','Miami')
)->get();
```

EDIT

In addition to the answer / comments here I found this helped me get the query perfect https://stackoverflow.com/a/41436703/7675570

Just in case anyone has similar scenarios it could help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `whereHas`:

```
thePage::select('field1','field2')
    ->with('pagePhotos')
    ->whereHas('pagePhotos', function($query) {
        $query->where('photoLocation', '=', 'Miami');
    })
    ->get();
```

[Laravel Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Edit:

If you want to be selective on the pagePhotos fields, instead of

```
->with('pagePhotos')
```

do pass param as array

```
->with(['pagePhotos' => function($query) {
    $query->select('field1', 'field2');
}])
```

Comment: thank you, this works like I wanted.  Is there an easy way to be selective on the pagePhotos fields it pulls in at this point? Or do I need to narrow it on the model itself?

Comment: @weekapaug just posted an edit to my answer to help you with this

Comment: I see, but thats an "instead" scenario.  Is there a way to select from both at this level? I know I can select it at the model level, but what about within the query here?

Comment: its not an instead scenario, you apply `whereHas` to filter and `with` to specify the fields you want to select from the relationship

Comment: I see, I did ->with('pagePhotos' => function($query) {
    $query->select('field1', 'field2')->where('photoLocation','=','Miami'); 
}) but I get all fields still.  This is another question at this point, sorry!!

Answer (score 6):

I think you should handle the query by using a closure.

```
thePage::select('field1','field2')->with(array('pagePhotos' => function($query) {
        $query->where('photoLocation','=','Miami');
}))->get();
```

Hope it can help you